# Playing a animated gif as a Movie only display canvas background

Tags: android, animated-gif

I would like to play an animated gif in my Android application.

I noticed that a WebView works fine with this code:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/gif.gif");
```

Unfortunately, the webView is too memory intensive and my app often crash.

I have seen a lot of tutorials using Movie like this one:

```
public class GIFView extends View {
    private Movie movie;
    private long moviestart;

    public GIFView(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("gif.gif"));
    }

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) throws IOException {
        super(context, attrs);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("gif.gif"));
    }

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
            throws IOException {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("gif.gif"));
    }

    private long _start_time;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        long _current_time = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (0 == _start_time) {
            _start_time = _current_time;
        }
        if (null != movie) {
            final int _relatif_time = (int) ((_current_time - _start_time) % movie
                    .duration());
            movie.setTime(_relatif_time);
            Log.i("",""+_relatif_time);
            double scalex = (double) this.getWidth() / (double) movie.width();
            double scaley = (double) this.getHeight() / (double) movie.height();
            canvas.scale((float) scalex, (float) scaley);
             movie.draw(canvas, (float) scalex, (float) scaley)
        }

        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

As I get a big red window, I can see that Canvas is drawn, and with the Log I added, I can see that my movie is not null and has a length!

Unfortunately, nothing appear in the canvas except the big red rectangle, and I have tested with different gif files.

Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a look at my library source code https://github.com/sbakhtiarov/gif-movie-view our just use it.

Comment: I tried your code and indeed it's working. The issue is that the animation is not taking care about the GIF frame time. As you know each frame has a time in ms that the animator has to take care and wait. The implementation of you class simple play frame after frame other on a constant speed.